# Youtube Video Post using Facebook Graph api

Tags: facebook, post, video

i have a php script for posting the video to my facebook page wall.

```
$attachment = array(
    'access_token' => $this->config->get('fb_auto_post_access_token'),
    'message' => 'Some text message',
    'link' => 'http://www.youtube.com/v/2omqg5PFJUY', //the video to embed
    'name' => 'Arke Uzaktan Eğitim Kurumsal Video',
    'caption' => 'Arke Uzaktan Eğitim Kurumsal',
    'picture' => 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/2omqg5PFJUY/default.jpg',
    'source' => 'http://www.youtube.com/v/2omqg5PFJUY', //the video to embed
    'description' => 'Some desc',
    'type' => 'video',
    'actions' => json_encode(array('name' => $this->config->get('config_name'),'link' => $parent_link ))
$this->facebook->api('/' . $pagenumber . '/videos','post', $attachment)
            );
```

when I run this script i see a error code "OAuthException: (#353) You must select a video file to upload." i cant solve this problem. what's wrong with this script.
Need help.

Comment: Why all this headache? you're not **uploading** a video on your timeline/wall, you're trying to post/share a YouTube video link use `/link` or `/feed`

Comment: Thanks but I want that the video is playable when its clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Like Adam Azad said you are simply sharing the video on Facebook

Thats is if you are using FacebookC#SDK to share video to Facebook wall all you need is following code

```
 var fb = new Facebook.FacebookClient(yourPageAccessToken); 
 argList["message"] = message;
 argList["link"] = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + YoutubeId;
 argList["source"] = "http://www.youtube.com/v/" + YoutubeId;
 argList["picture"] = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + YoutubeId + "/0.jpg";
 fb.Post("feed", argList);
```

This will post the video on your user's wall and it will be ready to play.